Unable to Configure ODBC for MongoDB on Windows 11
I'm facing issues while trying to configure ODBC on Windows 11.
I need to add the MongoDb driver (1.4.5 v) to the system DNS but it's pratically impossible to do it.
I have followed this tutorial in order to create the system DSN.
What i've done so far:
1- Installed the MongoDB driver 1.4.5 ( both 32 and 64 bits)

2- Installed the (2.14.12)MongoDB BI Connector
[]
(https://i.sstatic.net/82WLe93T.png)
3- Installed the "Visual C++ Redistributable for visual studio 2015" as the docs recommend

4 - Tried to add the MongoDB driver to the system DNS


5- Added the appropriate connections (ip adress to the server and port), username and password and pressed "test connection"
At the 5th step, the whole ODBC freeze and I can't add the driver to the system DNS.
I've done this with the 32 and 64 ODBC with MongoDB driver (for 32 and 64 bits respectively).
Additional steps I've taken:
Restarted my machine.
Pinging the server to ensure it is live (it is).
Here are my system specifications:

OS: Windows 11
MongoDB Version: [2.2.5]

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Has anyone faced a similar issue or can suggest a solution?

You missed one step. You downloaded and installed the MongoDB BI Connector but you did not create any service. The MongoDB BI Connector is a service which connects to your MongoDB and transforms the MonogDB BSON docuemnts into "SQL-like" data and then populates it to ODBC compliant data.
See What is the MongoDB Connector for BI?
You need to setup the mongosqld service, see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/bi-connector/current/reference/mongosqld/
Here is a sample mongosqld configuration file:
## https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/reference/mongosqld/#configuration-file

net:
  bindIp: localhost
  port: 3317
  ssl:
    mode: disabled

mongodb:
  net:
    uri: "mongodb://localhost:27017"
    ssl:
      enabled: false
    auth:
      username: admin
      password: secret
      source: admin
      mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-256

security:
  enabled: true
  defaultMechanism: SCRAM-SHA-256
  defaultSource: admin

systemLog:
  path: C:\MongoDB\log\mongosql.log 
  quiet: false
  verbosity: 1
  logAppend: true

schema:
  refreshIntervalSecs: 0
  stored:
    mode: "auto"
    source: "mongosqld_data"
    name: "myDatabase" # the named schema to read/write to in stored-schema modes
  sample:
    size: 1000 # The amount of random documents we sample from each collection.
    namespaces: ["myDatabase.*"]

processManagement:
  service:
    name: "mongosql"
    displayName: "MongoSQL Standalone"
    description: "MongoSQL accesses MongoDB - Standalone data with SQL"

When the configuration file is created, you can create and start the service for example with
mongosqld.exe install --config=c:\MongoDB\config\mongosqld.yml
net start mongosql

Then the ODBC DNS should work:

